# Tychonoff Theorem and the axiom of choice

Tags: general-topology, big-list, axiom-of-choice, compactness

How to show that

> The Tychonoff Theorem and the axiom of choice are equivalent?

Here I want to collect ways to prove it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that MSE is some "proof dictionary" where you can collect and classify proofs of certain propositions. There is one standard proof which appears on Wikipedia, and was given on this site not too long ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** J. Terilla, *Tychonoff’s Theorem*, P7.

[Theorem 9](http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/mbenders/notes4.pdf). *The Tychonoff theorem* $‎\Leftrightarrow‎$ *the axiom of choice* .

Comment: In what sense is this a hint?

Comment: @Martin: I've just referred Paul to see this sheets because I can't explain all the details to him.